# Find the index of a tuple when iterating across the first element of the tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, iteration

How can you identify the index of a tuple when looping through a list of tuples[0]?

```
List = [('SPAM', 1.0),('EGGS', 4.2),('SPAM', 4.4),('BACON', 9.0),('COFFEE', 2.3)]

for i,j in List:
    if i == 'SPAM':
        list.remove(???)

print(list)
```

I've tried to employ the Enumerate() function, but that didn't seem to give me the correct output either.

```
List.pop()
```

Doesn't pop the correct index all the time.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `del` to delete the element at the given index:

```
List = [('SPAM', 1.0),('EGGS', 4.2),('SPAM', 4.4),('BACON', 9.0),('COFFEE', 2.3)]

for (i, (e1, e2)) in enumerate(List):
    if e1 == 'SPAM':
        del List[i]

print(List) # prints [('EGGS', 4.2), ('BACON', 9.0), ('COFFEE', 2.3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration does work:

```
l = [('SPAM', 1.0),('EGGS', 4.2),('SPAM', 4.4),('BACON', 9.0),('COFFEE', 2.3)]

for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(l):
    if i == 'SPAM':
        print("FOUND SPAN at index %d" % idx)
```

However, you shouldn't mutate the list while iterating over it, rather take a filtering approach like so:

```
l_new = [(i, j) for i, j in l if i != 'SPAM']
```